# Get all images in a div using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing some complex interprocess JS on unknown pages so jquery is out of the question. How do I get all images within a div provided I have the ref of the div?

Something like :

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img")
```

But only within a div.

Comment: `thatDiv.getElementsByTagName("img")`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would just search for the div - let's make that it has an id of `myDiv`:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").getElementsByTagName("img");
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `querySelectorAll()` :

```
var all_imgs = document.querySelectorAll('#div_id img');
```

If you have the reference of the `div` you could use it as :

```
var all_imgs = my_div.querySelectorAll('img');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I would add that a benefit of this approach is `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` object which has useful methods like `forEach` whereas `getElementsByTagName` returns a `HTMLCollection`

Comment: @Damon That’s not true, `NodeList` doesn’t have such methods. Also, the OP said that the reference to the `<div>` already exists. This answer doesn’t use that reference.

Comment: It does in some newer browsers, though I guess the support is not wide enough to merit relying on. I stand corrected in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Simply call `getElementsByTagName` on your `<div>` element:

```
var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var images = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

or use `querySelectorAll`:

```
var images = div.querySelectorAll("#myDiv img");
```